# Replacing javascript selector with jquery selector breaks code

Tags: javascript

Im using the [dynamic.js](http://dynamicsjs.com/examples/basics.html) javascript library alongside jquery. The examples uses javascript selectors as follows:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#triangle')
```

When I attempt to use a jquery selector

```
var el = $('#triangle');
```

the code breaks. Could someone enlighten me please? Many thanks.

Comment: How is it breaking? And why do you need to use jQuery for this?

Comment: Assuming the problem isn't simply that you've neglected to import the jQuery library, you'll need to provide the error you're getting and post the code that actually causes the error.

Comment: Is your issue related to reuse of the variable? or is that just for example?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. Im using jQuery just out of familiarity. jQuery is imported, but thanks for the check. I had better create a codepen -  pen to illustrate my predicament. The issue is an example. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm including codepen using the solution below as reference  http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/qbRmQa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var el = $('#triangle'); // Is a jQuery object

var el = document.querySelector('#triangle'); // Is a DOM Level Object.
```

A jQuery object is an array-like object which contains DOM element(s). A jQuery object can contain multiple DOM elements and this thing depends on the used selector,  So you need to pick the first element of jQuery Object and it will be equivalent to the DOM level object.

**Use:**

```
$('#triangle')[0]; // Accesses the first DOM element in this jQuery object
$('#triangle').get(0); // is same as above
```

**Conside the following HTML Element**

```
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

**Then the following will produce same results:**

```
$('#triangle')[0];
$('#triangle').get(0);
document.getElementById("triangle");
```

Comment: It works, of course it works http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/qbRmQa/ thanks again